# How to choose the text without selection in jquery chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

The below is my code my problem is i just want to implement like kendo i mean not with selection when user types the text and if we won't select the text it should be selected from drop down list as like in [kendo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index)   In the below image you can see if you type medium and click mouse in sideways i mean without selecting with mouse it loads from drop down.

[image]

```js
$(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
<div>
          <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
          <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
            <option value=""></option>
            <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
              <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
              <option>New York Giants</option>
              <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
              <option>Washington Redskins</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
              <option>Chicago Bears</option>
              <option>Detroit Lions</option>
              <option>Green Bay Packers</option>
              <option>Minnesota Vikings</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC SOUTH">
              <option>Atlanta Falcons</option>
              <option>Carolina Panthers</option>
              <option>New Orleans Saints</option>
              <option>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC WEST">
              <option>Arizona Cardinals</option>
              <option>St. Louis Rams</option>
              <option>San Francisco 49ers</option>
              <option>Seattle Seahawks</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC EAST">
              <option>Buffalo Bills</option>
              <option>Miami Dolphins</option>
              <option>New England Patriots</option>
              <option>New York Jets</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC NORTH">
              <option>Baltimore Ravens</option>
              <option>Cincinnati Bengals</option>
              <option>Cleveland Browns</option>
              <option>Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC SOUTH">
              <option>Houston Texans</option>
              <option>Indianapolis Colts</option>
              <option>Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
              <option>Tennessee Titans</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC WEST">
              <option>Denver Broncos</option>
              <option>Kansas City Chiefs</option>
              <option>Oakland Raiders</option>
              <option>San Diego Chargers</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: But in your sample code, if you click outside of the select input, nothing happens.. This seems to be expected behavior right ?

Comment: yeah at the end of the video is shown wrong but if you see demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index you will understand what i want to achieve

Comment: @Rayon the text should be selected if we type the input but firstly need without selecting with mouse and if user wants with selecting with mouse

Comment: @overflowstack9: I believe that this how the 'chosen-jquery' plugin is designed and you won't be able to change that behaviour.

Comment: @kukkuz http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index i can use this plugin but the main problem is it calls all library //kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js thats y iam going to chosen-jquery  or can u suggest any other plugin like this which loads fast like chosen-jquery with expected behaviour as i said

Comment: @overflowstack9 : sorry, I'm not the right person to suggest a plugin I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to do so is once the dropdown is hidden - check if the value of the input is the same as the value of the first element in the drop down, and if so - trigger the `mouseup` for that element (inside the dropdown):

Check live sample:

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
$(".chosen-select").bind('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function(e, i) {
  searched_value = i.chosen.get_search_text();
  firstElementOnDropdown = i.chosen.search_results.find('li.active-result').first()
  if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase() == searched_value.toLowerCase()) {
    firstElementOnDropdown.trigger('mouseup');
    var t = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.chosen.input_blur();
    }, 150);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
      <option>Chicago Bears</option>
      <option>Detroit Lions</option>
      <option>Green Bay Packers</option>
      <option>Minnesota Vikings</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="NFC SOUTH">
      <option>Atlanta Falcons</option>
      <option>Carolina Panthers</option>
      <option>New Orleans Saints</option>
      <option>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="NFC WEST">
      <option>Arizona Cardinals</option>
      <option>St. Louis Rams</option>
      <option>San Francisco 49ers</option>
      <option>Seattle Seahawks</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AFC EAST">
      <option>Buffalo Bills</option>
      <option>Miami Dolphins</option>
      <option>New England Patriots</option>
      <option>New York Jets</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AFC NORTH">
      <option>Baltimore Ravens</option>
      <option>Cincinnati Bengals</option>
      <option>Cleveland Browns</option>
      <option>Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AFC SOUTH">
      <option>Houston Texans</option>
      <option>Indianapolis Colts</option>
      <option>Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
      <option>Tennessee Titans</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="AFC WEST">
      <option>Denver Broncos</option>
      <option>Kansas City Chiefs</option>
      <option>Oakland Raiders</option>
      <option>San Diego Chargers</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

### Update

Added `setTimeout` to `blur` the input (which cause the menu to close), since there is another `setTimeout` inside the code of `chosen` so needed to hide it after it's shown.

> Explanation: Inside the `chosen` code there is is a `setTimeout` function to show the menu. I needed to overcome this behavior so I added a new `setTimeout`, but with higher interval.

The `setTimeout` gets 2 arguments

- Function to run
- Time to wait (in milliseconds).

The function will run **after** the timeout is up. In my sample - the function is call the `input_blur` of the `chosen` menu (to make sure the menu is hidden), and I made sure it's called *after* 150 milliseconds).

Comment: good but the problem is i want to hide the scroll bar after selection view this image  http://oi66.tinypic.com/rkmnnk.jpg i mean the scrollbar should be closed after selection ........

Comment: can you explain this  t.chosen.input_blur();
    }, 150); i mean specially about 150.....

Comment: Added a better explanation there. Let me know if now it's better.

Comment: My last request there are many values appearing when we want to enter the text is it possible to resize the scroll bar to 4 or 5 values ......?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118697/discussion-between-overflowstack9-and-dekel).

Comment: your work is appreciable yeah definitely i will mark.......It is my last request as i said above

Comment: your work appreciable take my bounty @Dekel and solve my request as i said above

Comment: it is not working in my blogger platform http://myupdatesvijay.blogspot.in/ how can i achieve it @Dekel

Comment: the external resource http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js is exectuting first and above code which you have given is not executing how can i make it as !important ....?