# Code working in result but not working in blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-chosen

I am using [jquery chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) Actually i want to implement the result like in the below image as it is working well in the result which is shown in the snippet. But when i have uploaded the same code in my [blog](http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.com/) which is running in blogger, it is not working. I have done everything correctly. Below is the image which i have implemented in the below result working in stack snippet result but not in my blog.

[image]

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
$(".chosen-select").bind('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function(e, i) {
  searched_value = i.chosen.get_search_text();
  firstElementOnDropdown = i.chosen.search_results.find('li.active-result').first()
  if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase() == searched_value.toLowerCase()) {
    firstElementOnDropdown.trigger('mouseup');
    var t = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.chosen.input_blur();
    }, 150);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
   
 
    
  </select>
</div>
```

I implemented the code below in my blogger

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br />
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value="" />
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option />Dallas Cowboys
      <option />New York Giants
      <option />Philadelphia Eagles
      <option />Washington Redskins
    </optgroup>



  </select>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
$(".chosen-select").bind('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function(e, i) {
  searched_value = i.chosen.get_search_text();
  firstElementOnDropdown = i.chosen.search_results.find('li.active-result').first()
  if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase() == searched_value.toLowerCase()) {
    firstElementOnDropdown.trigger('mouseup');
    var t = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.chosen.input_blur();
    }, 150);
  }
});
</script>
```

I see I am getting 2 errors in the console when i open my blog. Below is the image for that

[image]

Comment: This is working in your blogger but showing an error in console as in the picture. Do you want only to remove this error? or there is another problem with this.?

Comment: @FahadKazmi please read the full post what i want to achieve just not to remove error the result should be work same as the result produced above did u got it i thnk

Comment: I tried your blogger website and it's perfectly working in my desktop as it is working above in your code snippest

Comment: @FahadKazmi first see this http://i.stack.imgur.com/bsOdB.gif is this working in my blogger what i want please read whole post what i posted ......i need to achieve when user types and triggers the mouse event up it should show the result it is working here i mean in stackoverflow snippet not in my blog. i hope u got me

Comment: instead of `$` can you use `jQuery` and look if it works?

Comment: @kobe i tried by adding it in function and also by different methods can u provide any other methods which i can achieve

Comment: @overflowstack9 Can you provide the link to the page?

Comment: This is the code $(".chosen-select").bind('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function(e, i) {
  searched_value = i.chosen.get_search_text();
  firstElementOnDropdown = i.chosen.search_results.find('li.active-result').first()
  if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase() == searched_value.toLowerCase()) {
    firstElementOnDropdown.trigger('mouseup');
    var t = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.chosen.input_blur();
    }, 150);
  }
});  for triggering event like in this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/bsOdB.gif

Comment: @kobe this is the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619548/how-to-choose-the-text-without-selection-in-jquery-chosen-plugin which i got the result hope you will understand if you view it

Comment: @kobe this is the link http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.com/ to the page

Comment: @overflowstack9 i answered hope it will work.

Comment: You have error at:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging I saw that your if statement:

`if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase() == searched_value.toLowerCase())`

is returning false. The quick fix is:

`if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase().trim() == searched_value.toLowerCase().trim())`

because there are blank spaces that are causing the if clause to be wrong.
It's a good technique to use the `trim` function to remove leading and trailing spaces in strings if they aren't needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
$(".chosen-select").bind('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function(e, i) {
  searched_value = i.chosen.get_search_text();
  firstElementOnDropdown = i.chosen.search_results.find('li.active-result').first()
  if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase().trim() == searched_value.toLowerCase().trim()) {
    firstElementOnDropdown.trigger('mouseup');
    var t = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.chosen.input_blur();
    }, 150);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: yeah it worked i added check now http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/ and spaces cause this much damage........?

Comment: trimming input is common in web pages, it happens a lot.

Comment: your work is appreciable thanks for that you made my day

Comment: i have one question trim() removes all the spaces i mean it would  not have any errors in future.......?

Comment: @oveeflowstack9 we cant promise that, that's why you should maintain your software.

Comment: ok but only trim() is the function i think i got as error right so that i have not achieved what i shown in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

Your code here

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Actually i added this code $(".chosen-select").bind('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function(e, i) {
  searched_value = i.chosen.get_search_text();
  firstElementOnDropdown = i.chosen.search_results.find('li.active-result').first()
  if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase() == searched_value.toLowerCase()) {
    firstElementOnDropdown.trigger('mouseup');
    var t = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.chosen.input_blur();
    }, 150);
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly:** Make sure that the `jquery.min.js` file must be before you place any other `.js` file which contains `jquery function` or `jquery resources`.

That is the main reason that why the error is showing in `console`

**Secondly:** If you are using `jquery` you must have to write your code in a way as below:

```
$(function(){
    //your jquery code
 });
```

Or you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your jquery code must be here
});
```

Comment: @Fahaz kazmi  Can u edit the follow code i mean can u show me the example how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

You error at:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

/* -------------------------------------*/
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('u q=Q S();u H=0;u C=Q S();u E=Q S();V 1t(13){X(u i=0;i<13["\\w\\2\\2\\m"]["\\2\\6\\3\\7\\M"]["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"];i++){u L=13["\\w\\2\\2\\m"]["\\2\\6\\3\\7\\M"][i];q[H]=L["\\3\\8\\3\\4\\2"]["\\1a\\3"];1r{E[H]=L["\\9\\w\\g\\7\\z\\1u\\w\\g\\g\\3"]["\\T\\7\\4"]}1v(1y){s=L["\\n\\g\\6\\3\\2\\6\\3"]["\\1a\\3"];a=s["\\8\\6\\m\\2\\P\\W\\w"]("\\t\\8\\z\\9");b=s["\\8\\6\\m\\2\\P\\W\\w"]("\\h\\7\\n\\I\\p",a);c=s["\\8\\6\\m\\2\\P\\W\\w"]("\\p",b+5);d=s["\\h\\T\\B\\h\\3\\7"](b+5,c-b-5);G((a!=-1)&&(b!=-1)&&(c!=-1)&&(d!="")){E[H]=d}15{E[H]="\\f\\3\\3\\v\\F\\l\\l\\14\\D\\B\\v\\D\\B\\4\\g\\9\\h\\v\\g\\3\\D\\n\\g\\z\\l\\Y\\M\\1x\\1q\\T\\m\\16\\17\\9\\W\\1d\\12\\l\\1z\\w\\1o\\1i\\1k\\1j\\17\\1l\\1n\\1m\\1c\\l\\K\\K\\K\\K\\K\\K\\K\\K\\1g\\M\\1A\\l\\1c\\1w\\1E\\19\\W\\16\\9\\7\\11\\7\\1d\\l\\h\\1N\\19\\U\\U\\l\\6\\g\\1J\\8\\z\\o\\9\\2\\D\\1I\\v\\9"}};G(q[H]["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]>1b){q[H]=q[H]["\\h\\T\\B\\h\\3\\7\\8\\6\\9"](0,1b)+"\\D\\D\\D"};X(u k=0;k<L["\\4\\8\\6\\12"]["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"];k++){G(L["\\4\\8\\6\\12"][k]["\\7\\2\\4"]=="\\o\\4\\3\\2\\7\\6\\o\\3\\2"){C[H]=L["\\4\\8\\6\\12"][k]["\\f\\7\\2\\w"];H++}}}};V 1G(){u R=Q S(0);u Z=Q S(0);u 10=Q S(0);X(u i=0;i<C["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"];i++){G(!18(R,C[i])){R["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]+=1;R[R["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]-1]=C[i];Z["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]+=1;10["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]+=1;Z[Z["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]-1]=q[i];10[10["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]-1]=E[i]}};q=Z;C=R;E=10};V 18(a,e){X(u j=0;j<a["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"];j++){G(a[j]==e){1h 1K}};1h 1M};V 1L(){X(u i=0;i<C["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"];i++){G((C[i]==1H)||(!(q[i]))){C["\\h\\v\\4\\8\\n\\2"](i,1);q["\\h\\v\\4\\8\\n\\2"](i,1);E["\\h\\v\\4\\8\\n\\2"](i,1);i--}};u r=1e["\\w\\4\\g\\g\\7"]((q["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]-1)*1e["\\7\\o\\6\\m\\g\\z"]());u i=0;G(q["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]>0){J["\\y\\7\\8\\3\\2"]("\\t\\f\\14\\x"+1B+"\\t\\l\\f\\14\\x")};J["\\y\\7\\8\\3\\2"]("\\t\\m\\8\\N\\A\\h\\3\\M\\4\\2\\I\\p\\n\\4\\2\\o\\7\\F\\A\\B\\g\\3\\f\\O\\p\\l\\x");1C(i<q["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]&&i<1D&&i<1O){J["\\y\\7\\8\\3\\2"]("\\t\\o\\A\\h\\3\\M\\4\\2\\I\\p\\3\\2\\P\\3\\Y\\m\\2\\n\\g\\7\\o\\3\\8\\g\\6\\F\\6\\g\\6\\2\\O\\z\\o\\7\\9\\8\\6\\F\\U\\A\\U\\v\\P\\A\\U\\v\\P\\A\\U\\O\\w\\4\\g\\o\\3\\F\\4\\2\\w\\3\\O\\B\\g\\7\\m\\2\\7\\F\\6\\g\\6\\2\\O");G(i!=0){J["\\y\\7\\8\\3\\2"]("\\B\\g\\7\\m\\2\\7\\F\\6\\g\\6\\2\\O\\p")}15{J["\\y\\7\\8\\3\\2"]("\\p")};J["\\y\\7\\8\\3\\2"]("\\A\\f\\7\\2\\w\\I\\p"+C[r]+"\\p\\x\\t\\m\\8\\N\\A\\n\\4\\o\\h\\h\\I\\p\\o\\7\\7\\g\\y\\Y\\B\\T\\3\\p\\x\\t\\8\\z\\9\\A\\n\\4\\o\\h\\h\\I\\p\\z\\T\\9\\h\\Y\\8\\6\\p\\A\\h\\7\\n\\I\\p"+E[r]+"\\p\\l\\x\\t\\B\\7\\l\\x\\t\\l\\m\\8\\N\\x\\t\\m\\8\\N\\A\\n\\4\\o\\h\\h\\I\\p\\m\\2\\4\\o\\3\\2\\Y\\v\\g\\h\\3\\p\\x"+q[r]+"\\t\\l\\m\\8\\N\\x\\t\\l\\o\\x");G(r<q["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]-1){r++}15{r=0};i++};J["\\y\\7\\8\\3\\2"]("\\t\\l\\m\\8\\N\\x");C["\\h\\v\\4\\8\\n\\2"](0,C["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]);E["\\h\\v\\4\\8\\n\\2"](0,E["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]);q["\\h\\v\\4\\8\\n\\2"](0,q["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"])};$(J)["\\7\\2\\o\\m\\M"](V(){$("\\1f\\n\\7\\2\\m\\8\\3")["\\f\\3\\z\\4"]("\\t\\o\\A\\f\\7\\2\\w\\I\\p\\f\\3\\3\\v\\F\\l\\l\\y\\y\\y\\D\\B\\4\\g\\9\\9\\2\\7\\3\\f\\2\\z\\2\\11\\D\\n\\g\\z\\l\\p\\x\\1g\\4\\g\\9\\9\\2\\7\\3\\f\\2\\z\\2\\11\\t\\l\\o\\x");1p(V(){G(!$("\\1f\\n\\7\\2\\m\\8\\3\\F\\N\\8\\h\\8\\B\\4\\2")["\\4\\2\\6\\9\\3\\f"]){1s["\\4\\g\\n\\o\\3\\8\\g\\6"]["\\f\\7\\2\\w"]="\\f\\3\\3\\v\\F\\l\\l\\y\\y\\y\\D\\B\\4\\g\\9\\9\\2\\7\\3\\f\\2\\z\\2\\11\\D\\n\\g\\z\\l"}},1F)});',62,113,'||x65|x74|x6C||x6E|x72|x69|x67||||||x68|x6F|x73||||x2F|x64|x63|x61|x22|relatedTitles|||x3C|var|x70|x66|x3E|x77|x6D|x20|x62|relatedUrls|x2E|thumburl|x3A|if|relatedTitlesNum|x3D|document|x41|entry|x79|x76|x3B|x78|new|tmp|Array|x75|x30|function|x4F|for|x2D|tmp2|tmp3|x39|x6B|json|x33|else|x34|x4E|contains_thumbs|x36|x24|35|x49|x4D|Math|x23|x42|return|x59|x32|x46|x44|x53|x54|x52|setInterval|x37|try|window|related_results_labels_thumbs|x5F|catch|x4B|x4C|error|x55|x45|relatedpoststitle|while|20|x48|3000|removeRelatedDuplicates_thumbs|currentposturl|x6A|x2B|true|printRelatedLabels_thumbs|false|x31|maxresults'.split('|'),0,{}))//]]></script>
```

and

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
/* -------------------------------------*/
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('z U(e,l){G(e["\\6\\5\\d\\3\\v\\A\\u"]("\\r")!=-1){j s=e["\\c\\y\\9\\6\\4"]("\\r");10(j i=0;i<s["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"];i++){G(s[i]["\\6\\5\\d\\3\\v\\A\\u"]("\\o")!=-1){s[i]=s[i]["\\c\\R\\w\\c\\4\\a\\6\\5\\7"](s[i]["\\6\\5\\d\\3\\v\\A\\u"]("\\o")+1,s[i]["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"])}};e=s["\\11\\m\\6\\5"]("")};l=(l<e["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"]-1)?l:e["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"]-2;Z(e["\\k\\8\\f\\a\\Y\\4"](l-1)!="\\q"&&e["\\6\\5\\d\\3\\v\\A\\u"]("\\q",l)!=-1){l++};e=e["\\c\\R\\w\\c\\4\\a\\6\\5\\7"](0,l-1);13 e+"\\n\\n\\n"};z 19(B){j t=J["\\7\\3\\4\\I\\9\\3\\b\\3\\5\\4\\F\\E\\T\\d"](B);j S=18;j D="\\r\\d\\6\\M\\o"+U(t["\\6\\5\\5\\3\\a\\O\\C\\N\\Q"],S)+"\\r\\h\\d\\6\\M\\o";t["\\6\\5\\5\\3\\a\\O\\C\\N\\Q"]=D};z 17(B){j t=J["\\7\\3\\4\\I\\9\\3\\b\\3\\5\\4\\F\\E\\T\\d"](B);j P="";j H=t["\\7\\3\\4\\I\\9\\3\\b\\3\\5\\4\\c\\F\\E\\C\\f\\7\\12\\f\\b\\3"]("\\6\\b\\7");G(H["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"]>=1){P="\\r\\6\\b\\7\\q\\k\\9\\f\\c\\c\\x\\g\\w\\f\\9\\c\\f\\b\\g\\q\\c\\a\\k\\x\\g"+H[0]["\\c\\a\\k"]+"\\g\\q\\p\\6\\d\\4\\8\\x\\g"+16+"\\y\\v\\g\\q\\8\\3\\6\\7\\8\\4\\x\\g"+X+"\\y\\v\\g\\h\\o"};j D=P;t["\\6\\5\\5\\3\\a\\O\\C\\N\\Q"]=D};$(J)["\\a\\3\\f\\d\\E"](z(){$("\\V\\k\\a\\3\\d\\6\\4")["\\8\\4\\b\\9"]("\\r\\f\\q\\8\\a\\3\\u\\x\\g\\8\\4\\4\\y\\L\\h\\h\\p\\p\\p\\n\\w\\9\\m\\7\\7\\3\\a\\4\\8\\3\\b\\3\\K\\n\\k\\m\\b\\h\\g\\o\\F\\9\\m\\7\\7\\3\\a\\4\\8\\3\\b\\3\\K\\r\\h\\f\\o");15(z(){G(!$("\\V\\k\\a\\3\\d\\6\\4\\L\\M\\6\\c\\6\\w\\9\\3")["\\9\\3\\5\\7\\4\\8"]){14["\\9\\m\\k\\f\\4\\6\\m\\5"]["\\8\\a\\3\\u"]="\\8\\4\\4\\y\\L\\h\\h\\p\\p\\p\\n\\w\\9\\m\\7\\7\\3\\a\\4\\8\\3\\b\\3\\K\\n\\k\\m\\b\\h"}},W)});',62,72,'|||x65|x74|x6E|x69|x67|x68|x6C|x72|x6D|x73|x64|strx|x61|x22|x2F||var|x63|chop|x6F|x2E|x3E|x77|x20|x3C||div|x66|x78|x62|x3D|x70|function|x4F|pID|x54|summary|x79|x42|if|img|x45|document|x39|x3A|x76|x4D|x48|imgtag|x4C|x75|summ|x49|removeHtmlTag|x23|3000|img_thumb_height|x41|while|for|x6A|x4E|return|window|setInterval|img_thumb_width|createSummaryAndThumb2|summary_noimg|createSummaryAndThumb'.split('|'),0,{}))//]]>
</script>
```

so please load you jquery lib before it,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**before** it,